# Does AWS classic load balancer keeps the SNI after tls termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, istio, amazon-elb

I have an AWS classic load balancer. Here are my listeners :

[image]

The `AWS classic load balancer` is doing tls termination, and redirecting the traffic to port `30925` of my nodes
The process listening on port `30925` is an istio gateway, redirecting traffic afterwards based on the `SNI` of the request

However, the `AWS classic load balancer` doesn't seems to keep the `SNI` of the request after tls termination

Is there any documentation regarding the behavior of the load balancer in that situation?
I found a couple of links talking about `SNI` ([here for example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html)), but it's only talking about the load balancer itself handling the routing of the `SNI`

Comment: I think this is the justified behavious as SNi is not supported for classic load balancer.You should rather switch to application and network for SNI capabilities.

Comment: What happens to the request after the ELB terminates TLS then? Is the load balancer just sending the request to NODE-IP:INSTANCE-PORT with the content of the request?

Comment: Just pass everything over TCP, and let your targets handle entire SSL processing, which will include SNI.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, i tried this and it indeed works fine. The issue is that in that case I have to make the certificate accessible to my applications inside the nodes. It was easier for me to just setup the tls termination on the load balancer and use self-signed certificates on my backend applications afterwards

Comment: @Patanouk If you terminate SSL on LB, nothing related to SSL is passed to targets. That's the entire point of termination - your targets do not have to care about ssl.

Comment: @Marcin I understand now, thanks for your explanations. One last question though : What happens when you setup an https listener on the instance side? The load balancer is just sending the request to https:// INSTANCE_IP:INSTANCE_PORT without verifying if the certificate is valid, if the host is matching etc...?

Comment: @Patanouk Usually you would use http between LB and your target. If you use https, then yes, LB does not care about ssl, thus self-signed certs are fine.

Comment: @Marcin Got it, thanks for the explanation. Feel free to reorganise your comments in an answer if you're interested in the checkmark, I will accept it. Else I will do it myself later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

If you terminate SSL on the load balancer (LB), SSL-related information is not carried over to your targets. To ensure full SSL-forwarding to your targets, you have to use **TCP listener**. This way your targets will be responsible for handling SSL, and subsequently will be able to custom process it.